# adding xml files to a queue in python

Tags: python

How would I add the xml files that are being created to a queue? This queue would be needed later to be executed by a pool of threads.

After executing, the queue must have 8000 xml files inside it.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import subprocess
import os

def frange(start, end, step):
    tmp = start
    while(tmp <= end):
        yield tmp
        tmp += ste

os.chdir('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC')
fileCount = 1
tree = ET.parse('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\IMLC_v4p8_Aravind.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.iter('Traces'):
    child.find('TS')
    child.find('TW')
    for i in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
        child.set('TS',str(i))
        for k in frange(3,12.75,0.25):
                child.set('TW',str(i))
                for child2 in root.iter('Stackup'):
                    child2.find('core_h')
                    for j in frange(2,4,0.5):
                        for child3 in root.iter('Definition'):
                            child3.set('modelname', 'Output{}.xml'.format(fileCount))
                            child2.set('core_h',str(j))
                            tree.write('C:\Users\Aravind_Sampathkumar\Desktop\IMLC\BO\Output{}.xml'.format(fileCount))
                            fileCount = fileCount+1
```

Comment: The fact that the file contains xml is totally irrelevant.

Comment: I basically meant that I want them to put into a queue. I

Comment: You use a Queue! https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: @Potato I think we all understood this, hopefully. It doesn't make the mention of "xml" more relevant.